# Entity Framework Batch Update by ID

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I'm using an Entity Framework project in which I need to batch update records by ID. The ID (i.e. the primary key of a particular table) is available at runtime, and I would like to update all records like in the following query:

```
UPDATE EntityTable
SET Column = @p0
WHERE EntityID IN '1,2,3,[...]'
```

The problem I'm running into is that I have around 60k IDs (at worst) that I will need to handle, and our database software (SQL Server 2008) can't handle this:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.

Through Google searches I've found people using old-school `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter` calls to accomplish this, but I'd like to stay within the spirit of Entity Framework if possible, or raw sql if necessary. Is there any way to do this in a reasonably efficient manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doesn't directly support batch updates so you have to use direct SQL. Your best choice is stored procedure with table valued parameter containing your IDs. EF doesn't support table valued parameters and because of that you have to use ADO.NET directly.

Your current solution can be improved only by dividing yours IDs into smaller groups and execute your update for each subset separately.

Comment: I ended up dividing into batches, passing ID lists as CSVs strings to a stored procedure. I do dislike parsing in queries but this turned out to be a pretty clean way to do it.